# Passive web application calling a WCF service with ajax (.NET 4.0 , adfs 2.0)

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, .net-4.0, adfs2.0

How Passive adfs 2.0 authenitcation for Web application can consume WCF Restful Services?

I am using ASP.NET 4.0, C# to develop web application and  WCF Rest Service.....

So could you please help me to understand how to secure Restful service using claim based authentication

Here is what I need: -

I have a Web App and WCF Rest service with webhttpbinding gets called from ajax jquery.

1. Now the user logs into the Web App which is relying party, he is redirected to the adfs    login page.
2. Once logged in, he is redirected back to the Web app.
3. This web app invokes the wcf Service.

Passive authentication is working fine but issue is when calling WCF service.

In ajax call for wcf service get undefined error. (namespace attribute is not getting added example

var svc = project.services.AjaxService()

where project does not include services and namespace attribute is missing which is present when same code is getting called from form authentication.

Where  project.services is namespace for service class AjaxService.

And also same service is getting called using Telerik controls WebServiceSettings.

Can anyone please help me in this. what configuration setting is required and anything else need to be added?

How can i achieve both using ajax and telerik.